# Java - Getting "Not authorized to access the application ID" error in Google Workspace Marketplace API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Google Workspace Marketplace app and want to determine which domains have installed or uninstalled it from my web app (written in Java, deployed on GAE).

I've enabled both GSuite Marketplace API and Google Workspace Marketplace SDK from the console. I'm using the same GCP project I've used to list my marketplace app while calling the relevant google [service](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification/list). But I keep getting the "Not authorized to access the application ID" 403 error. Here is the code:

```
    GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(SA_PRIVATE_KEY)
            .setServiceAccountId(SA_ID)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singletonList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license"))
            .build();

    GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://appsmarket.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/" + MY_APPLICATION_ID);

    HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(googleCredential);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(url).execute();
    return httpResponse.parseAsString();
```

I tried using the default service account with no luck. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification/list) doesn't explain much either. What am I missing? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the error so we know what is the problem. Maybe you need to set the params "?alt=json&max-results=200" And make sure the MY_APPLICATION_ID is just the numeric Google project ID with the marketplace config.

Comment: Did you resolve this in the end. I'm hitting the same issue.